# Upgrade to PHP 8.2: ksort and krsort changes

Tags: php, ksort, php-8.2

I am preparing upgrade to PHP 8.2 on a big application, and obviously going through changes between PHP 8.1 and 8.2. One of the BC breaking changes mentioned [HERE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration82.incompatible.php#migration82.incompatible.standard) is:

> ksort() and krsort() now do numeric string comparison under SORT_REGULAR using the standard PHP 8 rules now.

I don't seem to understand what this means. Since `ksort` sorts by keys, I assumed BEFORE it would **NOT** sort something like this:

```php
[
    '-5' => 'minus five',
    '4' => 'THIS SHOULD MOVE',
    '1' => 'one',
    '2' => 'two',
    '100' => 'hundred',
];
ksort($arr, SORT_REGULAR);
var_dump($arr);
```

But I used https://onlinephp.io/ and the it works just fine on 7.x, 8.1 and 8.2.
I tried with `SORT_REGULAR` and without.

```php
array(5) {
  [-5]=>
  string(10) "minus five"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [4]=>
  string(16) "THIS SHOULD MOVE"
  [100]=>
  string(7) "hundred"
}
```

Can someone explain to me what am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be more about mixing alpha and numeric keys, so in your example this isn't an issue.

If you change the array to be

```
$arr = [
    '-5' => 'minus five',
    'a' => 'THIS SHOULD MOVE',
    '1' => 'one',
    '100' => 'hundred',
    '2' => 'two',
];
```

prior to 8.2, this gives (tested with Result for 8.1.13, 8.0.26, 7.4.33: on https://onlinephp.io/)

```
array(5) {
  [-5]=>
  string(10) "minus five"
  ["a"]=>
  string(16) "THIS SHOULD MOVE"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [100]=>
  string(7) "hundred"
}
```

with the alpha being between the -ve and placed prior to the +ve numbers.

With 8.2, this instead will output

```
array(5) {
  [-5]=>
  string(10) "minus five"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [100]=>
  string(7) "hundred"
  ["a"]=>
  string(16) "THIS SHOULD MOVE"
}
```

The article at [PHP 8.2: ksort(..., SORT_REGULAR) sort order changes](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/ksort-SORT_REGULAR-order-changes) goes into this more with...

> Prior to PHP 8.2, ksort it placed alphabetical keys prior to numeric
> keys. For example, when sorting an array with a, b, 1, and 2 as keys,
> the sorted order would be a, b, 1, 2 because alphabetical keys are
> placed prior to numeric keys. Since PHP 8.2, ksort function is made
> consistent with the other array sort functions, and places numeric
> keys prior to alphabetical keys.